# Caused by: co.elastic.clients.util.MissingRequiredPropertyException: Missing required property 'ReloadDetails.index'

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the latest Synonyms API from Elastic Search.

Building the rules,

```
List<SynonymRule> rules = new ArrayList<>();
SynonymRule synonymRule = new SynonymRule.Builder().id("FR").synonyms("FT=>France").build();
rules.add(synonymRule);
```

then creating the request:

```
PutSynonymRequest putSynonymRequest = new PutSynonymRequest.Builder().id("global-rules").synonymsSet(rules).build();
PutSynonymResponse putSynonymResponse = esClient.putSynonym(putSynonymRequest);
```

and when executed getting this error:

> Caused by: co.elastic.clients.util.MissingRequiredPropertyException:
> Missing required property 'ReloadDetails.index'

As pert the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/put-synonyms-set.html), reloading of indices should happen automatically but this is a new API and I do not find any way to mention the missing property.

This is how I am creating the transport and client:

```
// Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
transport = new RestClientTransport(
          restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
// And create the API client
ElasticsearchSynonymsClient esClient = new ElasticsearchSynonymsClient(transport);
```